# How to get all the records having the same epoch timestamp in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with the following structure:

```
_embedded: {
    rh:doc: [
        {
            somevalue1: {...},
            somevalue2: "garbage1"
            interesting_date: 1520121600
        },
        {
            somevalue1: {...},
            somevalue2: "garbage2"
            interesting_date: 1520121600
        },
        {
            somevalue1: {...},
            somevalue2: "garbage3"
            interesting_date: 1520121600
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

How to get all the records having the same "interesting_date" value using MongoDB filters?

This collection is accessed via RESTHeart, so I have to pass the filters in the URI itself via an http request in Java.

I am very new to the application side development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only find that data with same date then you can perform your query like this..

```
db.user.find({ interesting_date: 1520121600 });
```

Otherwise You can use `$group` for ex.

```
db.user.aggregate(
[
  {
    $group : {
       _id : '$interesting_date' },

    }
  }
]);
```

Or you can apply `$filter` while `$project`

```
db.user.aggregate([
{
  $project: {
     interesting_date: {
        $filter: {
           input: "$doc",
           as: "item",
           cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.interesting_date", 1520121600 ] }
        }
     }
  }
}
]);
```